# fetching unconfirmed utxos from blockchain.info

Tags: api, blockchain.info, utxo

A few weeks ago, I would retrieve **unconfirmed** utxos from Blockchain.info doing API call https://blockchain.info/unspent?active=$address. 
That enabled me to successfully make a micropayment channel (MPC) for instance.

Since last week however, an API call for an address with unconfirmed utxos only yields:

```
{
    "notice" :"Some funds are pending confirmation and cannot be spent yet (Value 0.00412834 BTC)",
    "unspent_outputs":[

    ]
}
```

(I know it s just a matter of time before these utxos are confirmed and the issue is sorted but ... )

which implies my MPC will not work anymore.

**Why such a change?** 
or **have I gotten something wrong?**

I am considering [this](https://blockchain.info/address/19ScG5PughZ3wNVRv1PtWsfSH7NDG4Jg5M) address. **We can see the unconfirmed balance is not null, but the API returns no (unconfirmed) UTXO.**

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely something on blockchain.info's end. You have a very similar call available via API to blockcypher.com here:

https://dev.blockcypher.com/#address-endpoint

unspentOnly=true will get you what you want.

Comment: Thx for this answer, but `curl https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/addrs/17wT1VgpwdWqvLza8y2AVWoiLpaLJ8XHq?unspentOnly=true` did not return the unconfirmed utxos I am looking for, even though this transaction (id: `If4cc19aa44b1f8dce6a477ccbe0cee06ff89fc3533d03ab9d3ae233dc416699c`), which is unconfirmed, should I believe result in some unconfirmed utxos... I feel like there is something I did not understand ... ?

Comment: any help will be welcome

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could see, this results (for some reason I ignore) from the fact that some of the outputs of the transaction were too low (dust). All the transactions with this property seem to be treated this way.

Comment: Most nodes don't relay transaction's with dust outputs, and afaik miners won't confirm them (the transactions are valid though, if a miner includes them in a block).